# how to prevent another where chain from quering db again

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an object called `work_shift_stops` created with .where and after modified to limit `start` and `end_time`, with code below:

```
  work_shift_stops = Stoppage20.where(["machine20_id = :machine20_id AND (end_time >= :start AND start <= :end_time)",
    { machine20_id: params[:shift_result][:machine20_id], 
      end_time: work_shift.end, 
      start: work_shift.first}])
  work_shift_stops.each do |ws|
    ws.start = work_shift.first if ws.start < work_shift.first
    ws.end_time = work_shift.end if ws.end_time > work_shift.end
  end
```

Further in my code I am using another where chain on the object:

```
  load_time = open_time - work_shift_stops.where(stop20_id: Stop20.where(stop_group20_id: 3).pluck(:id)).sum(:duration)
```

This gives unpleasant result as rails is making another db query, which retrieves `work_shift_stops` with unmodified `start` and `end_time` limits:

```
SELECT SUM("stoppage20s"."duration") AS sum_id FROM "stoppage20s" WHERE (machine20_id = '1' AND (end_time >= '2013-03-02 05:00:00.000000' AND start <= '2013-03-02 17:00:00.000000')) AND "stoppage20s"."stop20_id" IN (12, 17)
```

Question is how to prevent rails from making another db query and use object with modified attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually did was dropping .sum(:duration) function and iterating on active record collection `work_shift_stops`with modified `start` and `end_time`:

```
work_shift_stops.each do |wsd|
    planned_stops_time += wsd.duration if Stop20.where(stop_group20_id: 3).pluck(:id).include? wsd.stop20_id 
    tech_stops_time += wsd.duration if Stop20.where(stop_group20_id: 1).pluck(:id).include? wsd.stop20_id
    org_stops_time += wsd.duration if Stop20.where(stop_group20_id: 2).pluck(:id).include? wsd.stop20_id
end
```